# How to stop propagating event from parent div in child select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There's a div element that contains 1 or more child elements of type select. When the div (my_title) is clicked, sort() has to run (OK). If a value is selected from the select (my_select), sort() is executed as well but it shouldn't. I tried to add a click handler and call stopPropagation() but sort() is still called. In fact, sort() is called first and only then stopPropagation().

```
<div id="my_title" onclick="sort(&quot;sf&quot;, &quot;2&quot;, event)" style="top: 0px; left: 1px; width: 300px; height: 50px; text-align: center; position: absolute;">
   Column 2
   <select id="my_select" style="top: 1px; left: 0px; width: 297px; position: relative;" >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sort() {
    console.log('sort');
}

$('#my_title').on('click', '> select', function(event) {
    console.log('stopPropagation');
    event.stopPropagation();
    // event.cancelBubble = true;
    // event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/34nh6Lwb/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no success when I listen for change. The html cannot be changed, it's as it is.

Comment: I added an answer below with more explanation and a working example

Comment: Your event fires on `#my_title` (the parent) - so it's *already* propagated.  Stopping propagation at this point will stop it going higher than #my_title, not higher than the original element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop event propagation between the target element and the delegated parent when using a delegated event handler. This is because the event needs to propagate up the DOM from the element that raises the event to the one which the handler is bound to.

A better solution in this case is to determine which element raised the `click` event handler and then only call `sort()` if it was the `#my_title` element.

Also note that your JS can be improved. Firstly, you should not bind JS event handlers or add styling in to the HTML. They should be placed in external JS and CSS files, respectively.

In addition, event handlers should be bound unobtrusively (as you do for the `select` element) not using outdated `onX` attributes which are bad practice.

Finally, use the `change` event on the `select` to listen for updates, not the `click` event.

With all those points addressed, your code should look like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#my_title').on('click', e => {
    let $el = $(e.target);
    if ($el.is('#my_title'))
      sort($el.data('sort-key'), $el.data('sort-value'));
  });

  $('#my_title').on('change', '> select', function(event) {
    // change handler logic here...
    console.log('change');
  });
});

let sort = (key, value) => {
  // your sort logic here...
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

```css
#my_title {
  top: 0px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

#my_select {
  top: 1px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 297px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_title" data-sort-key="sf" data-sort-value="2">
  Column 2
  <select id="my_select">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: That's true - I should have been more specific. I mean that you cannot stop propagation between the target element and the delegated parent. I'll update

Answer (score 1):

Seems that that behavior happens when you use onclick="..."

Try using this instead:

```
$('#my_title').on('click', function(event) {
  sort()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sort to something like this:

```
function sort(a, b, e) {
        if (e.target.id === 'my_title') { // or use more generic comparison
            console.log('sort');
    }
}
```

It will only run for elements that much your comparison (eg your Label/Title